# Why does the .NET framework have no concept of classes as first-class types?

Tags: architecture, .net, history, delphi

It's well known to those familiar with the history that C# and the .NET framework started out as essentially "Delphi rewritten to feel like Java," architected by the chief developer behind Delphi, Anders Hejlsberg.  Things have diverged quite a bit since then, but early on the similarities were so obvious that there was even some [serious speculation that .NET was actually originally Borland's product.](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphifornet/a/conspiracydnet.htm)

But I've been looking at some .NET stuff lately, and one of the most interesting and useful features from Delphi seems to be missing entirely: the concept of classes as a first-class data type.  For those not familiar with it, the type `TClass` represents a reference to a class, similar to the `Type` type in .NET.  But where .NET uses `Type` for reflection, Delphi uses `TClass` as a very important built-in part of the language.  It allows for various useful idioms that simply don't and can't exist without it, such as class subtype variables and virtual class methods.

Every OO language has virtual methods, in which different classes implement the same fundamental concept of a method in different ways, and then the right method gets called at runtime based on the actual type of the object instance it's called on.  Delphi extends this concept to classes: if you have a TClass reference defined as a specific class subtype (ie `class of TMyClass` means that the variable can accept any class reference that inherits from `TMyClass`, but not anything outside the heirarchy) that has class-scope virtual methods attached to it, they can be called without an instance by using the actual type of the class.  Applying this pattern to constructors makes a Factory implementation trivial, for example.

There doesn't seem to be anything equivalent in .NET.  With as useful as class references (and especially virtual constructors and other virtual class methods!) are, has anyone said anything about why they were left out?

### Specific Examples

#### Form Deserialization

The Delphi VCL saves forms in `DFM` format, a DSL for describing a component hierarchy.  When the form reader parses DFM data, it runs across objects that are described like this:

```
object Name: ClassName
   property = value
   property = value
   ...
   object SubObjectName: ClassName
      ...
   end
end
```

The interesting thing here is the `ClassName` part.  Each component class registers its `TClass` with the component streaming system at `initialization` time (think static constructors, only slightly different, guaranteed to happen immediately on startup.)  This registers each class in a string->TClass hashmap with the class name as the key.

Each component descends from `TComponent`, which has a virtual constructor that takes a single argument, `Owner: TComponent`. Any component can override this constructor to provide for its own initialization.  When the DFM reader reads a class name, it looks up the name in the aforementioned hashmap and retrieves the corresponding class reference (or raises an exception if it's not there), then calls the virtual TComponent constructor on it, which is known to be good because the registration function takes a class reference that is required to descend from TComponent, and you end up with an object of the proper type.

Lacking this, the WinForms equivalent is... well... a big mess to put it bluntly, requiring any new .NET language to completely re-implement its own form (de)serialization.  This is a bit shocking when you think about it; since the whole point of having a CLR is to let multiple languages use the same basic infrastructure, a DFM-style system would have made perfect sense.

#### Extensibility

[An image manager class I wrote](https://code.google.com/p/turbu/source/browse/trunk/classes/sdl%20custom/SDL_ImageManager.pas) can be provided with a data source (such as a path to your image files) and then load new image objects automatically if you attempt to retrieve a name that's not in the collection but is available in the data source.  It has a class variable typed as `class of` the base image class, representing the class of any new objects to be created.  It comes with a default, but there are some points, when creating new images with special purposes, that the images should be set up in different ways.  (Creating it without an alpha channel, retrieving special metadata from a PNG file to specify sprite size, etc.)

This could be done by writing extensive amounts of configuration code and passing in special options to all of the methods that might end up creating a new object... or you could just make a subclass of the base image class that overrides a virtual method where the aspect in question gets configured, and then use a try/finally block to temporarily replace the "default class" property as needed and then restore it.  Doing it with class reference variables is far simpler, and is not something that could be done with generics instead.

Comment: Probably [because it wasn't a high-priority feature that fit into C# team's budget](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156303/why-does-f-have-an-interactive-mode-but-not-c/156330#156330).

Comment: I think your initial premise may be incorrect.  While it is true that Anders came from Borland, C# is C++/Java reloaded, not a clone of Delphi with curly brackets.  VB.NET resembles Pascal and Delphi more than C# does.

Comment: Can you provide one or two concrete examples where a `TClass` is useful, with some sample code?  In my cursory internet research about `TClass`, I am finding that `TClass` can be passed around as a parameter.  This is done in .NET using Generics.  Factory methods are simply marked `static` in .NET, and don't require a class instance to execute.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Edited to give a few examples, explaining how a virtual constructor is far more powerful than a `static` factory method, and how class references can provide customizability that generics can't.

Comment: This basically requires `kind`s to satisfy the "class of X" behavior. C# didn't get anything similar until generic constraints.  Given the relative utility of generics, if they didn't spend the effort for _them_ I can't imagine that they'd do the work for this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: To me, personally, C# started to make a lot more sense once I *stopped* looking at it as Java/C++ reloaded and started treating it as Modula-2 with objects. It's the same with Java: everybody says it was influenced by C++, but that's not true. Its main influence is Objective-C (and Smalltalk via that), and Java will make a *lot* more sense once you treat it as Smalltalk with types instead of C++ with GC.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Fair enough.

Comment: Well, as far as serialization is concerned, Microsoft has two on-board ways to do it: binary and XML.  There are outboard libraries that can do it in JSON, or pretty much whatever format you want.  Serialization works on any .NET object; a form is just a collection of such objects.  Having a common infrastructure also means having the flexibility to serialize the way you want; DFM strikes me as *proprietary.*  In any event, there's no scenario that requires you to re-invent serialization from scratch.

Comment: Actually, Delphi seems to be the odd one out here. Dynamic OO languages usually have classes as objects (in Smalltalk, [every class has a metaclass of which it is the only instance](http://pharo.gforge.inria.fr/PBE1/PBE1ch14.html), in Ruby, all classes are instances of class `Class` and you can create new classes at runtime the same way that you can create every other object at runtime, by simply calling `Class.new`), most static OO languages don't do it that way. I find classes-as-objects very useful, so I don't know why the static OO languages don't have them, and am glad Delphi does.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I'm not entirely convinced.  The Python guys say that metaclasses are useful.  They also say that you don't need them (and shouldn't use them) about 99 percent of the time.

Comment: Regarding the image example, what prevents you from simply writing  your own TClass (or TImage), and just inheriting from that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: `TClass` is a fundamental language feature that requires compiler support.  You can't "write your own" without writing your own language, and for .NET even that would not be sufficient because the object model is defined by the CLR, not by individual languages.  It's something that literally needs to be part of the .NET framework itself, or it can't exist.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: As for DFM being proprietary, sure.  If I had to implement something like that today, I'd use JSON, obviously.  But Delphi and the DFM format came out in 1995, predating both XML (1996) and JSON (2002).  What else could they have done?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the supposed benefits of `TClass` - how does it differ from either interfaces or standard inheritance?  I can use an `MySubClass` anywhere that's expecting `MyClass` or `ISubClass`.

Comment: @Bobson: It's not an interface or an inheritance mechanism; it's something fundamentally different that does not exist anywhere in .NET or Java.  TClass is not an object; it's its own primitive type that represents a class and allows access to class-scoped members, including class-scoped virtual methods and virtual constructors, without any need for reflection.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - Either I'm completely missing the point (very possible), or you missed mine.  How is using `TClass of MyClass`, then stuffing a `MySubClass` into it different from C# where you declare a `MyClass` variable and stuff a `MySubClass` into it?

Comment: @Bobson: Yes, `TClass` understands the class inheritance heirarchy.  But it's something fundamentally different because a `class of MyClass` is not an object of type `MyClass`; it's a reference to the class itself.  (Specifically, to the VMT of the class, which also holds a bunch of metadata on it, but that's an implementation detail.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler - Ah, I think I see now.  The closest equivalent would probably be a covariant generic parameter, but it's not a great fit.   I'm still not sure why `TClass` is helpful, but I understand what it is and does now.

Comment: @Bobson: [Care to join me in chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16756/class-references)

Comment: It's been ages since I used Delphi (about 15 years), so I don't remember TClass, but it sounds like something I've thought .NET languages could implement without too much difficulty if a convention were defined to allow interaction.  Basically, the idea would be to say that if a class defines a static virtual method, the compiler should define a nested class which contains that method as well as a nested static generic class whose generic parameter is constrained to the outer class type; that static class should contain a static singleton reference of the former class's type, along with...

Comment: ...some Reflection-based code to set it up. Given `class Foo { virtual static boz();...}`, within `class Moo<T> where T:Foo`, a call to `T.boz()` should get rendered as `Foo.StaticHelperHolder<T>.helper.boz()`.  The first such call for any given type `T` would require Reflection, but all calls after that would use the `helper` object created by the first.  Does that sound like what you'd be seeking?

Comment: First of all, I can say with utmost certainty that .NET wasn't a "Borland" product originally. How do I know this? I was (still am) part of the original core team which developed Delphi. I worked closely with Anders, Chuck, Gary and others. Of course, I'm certain that you know this. As for the existence of a class reference (as TClass and similar constructs are called) in .NET was likely deemed unnecessary due to the existence of rich run-time accessible type information. Delphi had far less type information in the beginning and class refs were a compromise.

Comment: @Allen: Good to see you on here.  I'm not sure I agree, though. It may be regarded as "a compromise" by people on the .NET side without experience with Delphi, but you and I know better. Can you truly say with a straight face that `Activator.CreateInstance()` is *in any way* a better solution to the problem solved by virtual constructors?

Comment: @Mason Well, my cynical view is this; Anders had a bunch of inexperienced never-been-in-the-real-world academics on his team who vociferously argued that class references were a clear hack and the only "true" way to do this is to listen to their clearly superior years of research inside the the self-actualizing academic bubble. Anders was relatively new and didn't want to rock to the boat. Is that a better explanation? IOW, I agree with you that virtual constructors are a better solution. Reminds me of this: http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-09

Comment: @AllenBauer: Heh. Fair enough.

Comment: I, too, miss Delphi's meta class concept (and construct) in Delphi's language (that wasn't reify in the CLR/CTS design) of "class of T..." and virtual constructors. E.g., among other things, in many abstract factory pattern use cases, the latter can simply be expressed as: "type TMyMetaClass = class of TMyClass; TMySubMetaClass = class of TMySubClass; etc" and still statically type-check sub types when one later writes: "myObj := myMetaClass.Create(...)". IMO, it's not just about code terseness but also to avoid boring (boilerplate) singletons, making sure the init of those is thread safe, etc

Comment: *class of TMyClass means that the variable can accept **any** class reference that inherits from TMyClass* .... Could one say that C# covariance and contravariance is the same idea albeit limited?

Comment: A clarification: The feature is called "classes as first-class *values*" when classes can be treated as other values - assigned to variables, passed as arguments etc. Classes are first-class types in C#, but they are not first-class values.

Answer (score 5):

.NET (the CLR) was the third generation of Microsoft's Component Object Model (COM), which in the early days referred to as the "COM+ runtime".   Microsoft Visual Basic and the COM/ActiveX controls market has had much more influence on the specific CLR architectural compatability choices than Borland Delphi.    (Admittedly the fact that that Delphi had adopted ActiveX controls certainly helped grow the ActiveX ecosystem,  but COM/ActiveX existed before Delphi)

COM's architecture was worked out in C (not C++) and focused on interfaces, rather than classes.   Furthermore supported object composition, meaning that a COM object could in fact be made up of several different objects, with the IUnknown interface linking them together.  But IUnknown had no role in COM object creation, which was designed to be as language-independent as possible.   Object creation was generally handled by IClassFactory, and reflection by ITypeLibrary and related interfaces.   This separation of concerns was independent of implementation language, and the features of each core COM interface were kept minimal and orthogonal.

So as a result of the popularity of COM and ActiveX controls, .NET architecture was built to support on the COM IUnknown, IClassFactory, and ITypeLibrary.   In COM, these interfaces were not necessarily on the same object, so lumping these together didn't necessarily make sense.

Answer (score 0):

C# supports generics which have functionality overlapping with classes as  first-class values. For example:

```
void Foo<TClass>() where TClass: TMyClass { ... }
```

will accept a type parameter which is a subtype of `TMyClass`. Generics are different from first-class types in that type parameters use a separate syntax from reqular parameters, but conceptually it is the same.

Given the support for generics there wouldn't be much benefit to simultaneously support classes as first-class values. And generics are more powerful in general, so it is not surprising c#/.net went in that direction.

Some features are not supported though: Overriding class-level members. This could also be supported through generics but is not. Most likely this feature was just not considered useful enough to include.

Comment: It was likely regarded too complex: Add it, and you take a big step to full templates.